# setting element's style.backgroundColor not working in IE8?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

[Re-edited question]

A simple piece of code:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.style["background-color"] = "#DDD";
newDiv.innerHTML = " (some content) ";
container.appendChild(newDiv);
```

(object "container" is defined earlier)

In latest version of Chrome, the new div box appears with grey background, in IE8 the background is transparent. If I change to this:

```
newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#DDD";
```

the box's background is grey also in IE8. Why is this? I have not yet tested in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work correctly in IE8 and IE9 specify the proper doctype at the start of your document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using internet explorer 8 and your code works in my browser but with a little trick - setting the height of the DIV

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#DDD";
container.appendChild(newDiv);

//this new addition showed it worked
newDiv.style.height = '50px';
```

OR use

```
newDiv.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
```

Probably because the div does not have content, it is not showing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the .innerHTML property of newDiv is also assigned a value later in the code. Edited the question.

Comment: Works when the div has content e.g. with .innerHTML set. See my update